# Machine Learning course material

Tags: machine-learning, references

I am undertaking a course of Machine learning by Prof Ng on coursera. I wish to know what notes or any reference material I should refer as along the course there are number of doubts that I wish to understand.  So what text should I prefer for it?

Comment: He has a lot of additional notes related to his original stanford course here: http://cs229.stanford.edu/materials.html